# aspx page not getting cached on the browser

Tags: asp.net, caching, browser-cache

No matter what I do I cannot seem to cache my aspx pages locally on the browser. The first request for a page after login goes to the server and retrieves it from there. The 2nd request onwards, the pages are fetched form local cache. However as soon as I signout and sign back in, the same page is yet again fetched from the server and not taken from the cache locally.

URL of my page is as follows:

```
http://mywebsite.net/page1.aspx?v=2015_3.0&ln=en-EN&sid=612e0d3f-f29d-4b98-b4f7-6788e5a35a03
```

Response Header of the Page looks like this:

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=31536000
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:18355
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 03 Sep 2015 15:34:59 GMT
Expires:Fri, 02 Sep 2016 15:34:56 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 03 Sep 2015 15:34:56 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

In my aspx code behind this is what I had set

```
resp.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate)
resp.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(True)
resp.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1))
resp.Cache.SetMaxAge(New TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0))          
resp.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.UtcNow)            
resp.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(True)
resp.Cache.VaryByParams.Item("v") = True
resp.Cache.VaryByParams.Item("ln") = True
resp.Cache.VaryByParams.Item("sid") = False
```

Can anyone please suggest why would the browser not take the page from local cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happening since the query string was changing constantly, hence the browser was ignoring the cached page.